# How to assign the location of button?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

How can we create a button on the frame that is in North and in center horizontally? (i.e not occupy all the width)?

Comment: yes this is Swing. I mean is there a way other than following statement for specifying the location of button as we want? 
fram.addContentPane().add(BorderLayout.North, button);

Answer (score 2):

`BorderLayout` expands components in the `NORTH` location to fill the width of the container. Therefore you need to place it in another container that respects the preferred size of the component, the `JButton` in this case. You can use the default `FlowLayout` in `JPanel`:

```
JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(); 
JButton button = new JButton("OK");
frame.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

try solution like this:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    public MyFrame(){
      super();
      JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      JButton myButton = new JButton("MyButton");
      JPanel myPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout.Center));
      myPanel.add(myButton);
      contentPane.add(myPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER); 
      setContentPanel(contentPane);
    }
```

}

when you wrap button in jpanel it saves it width, and center layout place it in the center

Comment: yes, there are 2 misspelings: BorderLaylout --> BorderLayout and new Jbutton( -->new JButton(

Comment: thanks, I did not think about it. I corrected it, now it seems to be ok